# ffmpeg trim multiple videos

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I need to trim down alot of videos to the same timeframe but cannot get a loop to work that would do it for all videos at once.

I usually use the command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm -ss 00:00:05 -t 00:00:05 -c:v copy -c:a copy output1.webm
```

to trim individual videos.

I have tried to trim multiple videos with the loop:

```
for f in *.webm; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -ss 00:00:05 -t 00:00:05 -c:v copy -c:a copy "${f%.*}.webm"; done
```

However, I get a "Missing opening'(' after keyword 'for'." error

I have tried with some different brackets at different points but can't get the loop to work. Do you guys have some ideas for how to fix the loop?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is likely because you're trying to run the loop in a shell that doesn't support the `for` loop syntax you're using. It appears to be a syntax issue specific to your shell.

You can try using a different shell or use a more generic loop construct that should work in most shells. Here's an alternative loop using the `find` command to locate all `webm` files in the current directory and then processing them with `ffmpeg`:

```bash
find . -name "*.webm" -exec ffmpeg -i {} -ss 00:00:05 -t 00:00:05 -c:v copy -c:a copy {}.output.webm \;
```

This command will find all `.webm` files in the current directory and its subdirectories, then apply the `ffmpeg` command to each of them, trimming them and appending ".output" to the filename to create the output files. This should work in most Unix-like shells.